# No longer getting caller ID name with Cisco CM

Tags: cisco

We have a Cisco Call Manager installation with 7941/7961 phones, and a Cisco 2811 voice gateway. We're getting phone service from Windstream using their SIP terminating in PRI for our phone system. Before we upgraded our internet and phone services, we were using a regular PRI setup and both caller ID number and name worked. Now we're just getting caller ID number, with no name.

Where do I start looking?

Comment: Windstream. If I'm reading your rambling correctly, you are handed a PRI. That PRI isn't signalling name+number.

Comment: Correct I guess, I'm just going off what I heard from Windstream. Although they claim they are sending the correct info. I'm trying to understand why it worked before, why it isn't working now, and how to fix it. I'm not a telephony/networking guy.

We do get the phone number calling, but not the name.

Comment: `debug isdn q931` (or q921 if you want to get deeper) will show what the telco is sending to you. CNAM should appear in the initial setup message or a subsequent facility IE.

Comment: Ok, here is the log I got from a test call https://file.io/SoCyMz

Comment: @RickyBeam you are rude.  The guy is not rambling, he is asking a question.  Also, the PRI may be signalling it but his PRI gateway not supporting it.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

With a PRI gateway, you can set it up as MCGP controlled or as an H.323 gateway.  I know that (back a few years ago), MGCP was not supporting passing name and number.  That may be fixed now.  Look at how your PRI gateway is configured.

This is a classic (and old) question.  You'll be able to get it working, provided your carrier is delivering it - which they should be (just ask them).

http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/voice-unified-communications/unified-communications-manager-callmanager/44102-cm-call-id-issues.html

Comment: I know of ZERO telcos that allow customers to mess with their hardware. He'll have no visibility or control of the thing on the other end of the PRI. Hence my comment... if Windstream isn't providing it, he cannot change that. (q931 messages will confirm what's being sent.)

Comment: From what I can tell in the Call Manager, it's setup as an h.323 gateway

Comment: It sounds like you migrated to a new PRI.  After the migration, the calling name stopped being displayed on your handsets.  To ensure that you are not getting calling name issue a `debug isdn q931` if I remember correctly.  If the name ain't there, the telco ain't sending it to you.  So, problems on their end.  If you see the calling name and it's not displaying on your handsets, the problem is with your config.